# How to use React refs with new Typescript strictPropertyInitialization option?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The following is the class I wrote to help me with using Bootstrap's Popover functionality.

```
import * as React from "react"
import {PureComponent, SyntheticEvent} from "react";
import {EventUtil} from "appUtil/EventUtil";

export interface PopoverProps extends React.HTMLProps<HTMLElement>{
  popoverTitle: string | Element | Function;
  popoverContent: string | Element | Function;
  container?: string;
  allowDefaultClick?: boolean;
}

export class Popover
extends PureComponent<PopoverProps, object> {

  selfRef: HTMLSpanElement;

  componentDidMount(): void{
    $(this.selfRef).popover({
      container: this.props.container || this.selfRef,
      placement: "auto",
      title: this.props.popoverTitle,
      content: this.props.popoverContent,
      trigger: "focus",
    });
  }

  stopClick = (e: SyntheticEvent<any>) =>{
    if( !this.props.allowDefaultClick ){
      EventUtil.stopClick(e);
    }
  };

  render(){
    // tabIndex is necessary when using "trigger=focus" to get 
    // "dismiss on next click" behaviour 
    return <span 
      tabIndex={0}
      ref={(ref)=>{if(ref) this.selfRef = ref}} 
      data-toggle="popover"
      onClick={this.stopClick}
    >
      {this.props.children}
    </span>;

  }
}
```

This works fine, but when I enable `strictPropertyInitialization`, the compiler reports:

```
TS2564: Property 'selfRef' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
```

**NOTE**: I am already working around this by using the definite assignment operator, i.e.

```
selfRef!: HTMLSpanElement;
```

But that doesn't seem like "The Right Thing" - I feel like this is just highlighting the fact that I'm not doing the right thing with how I use React refs, but I don't what the right way is.

I don't want to declare `selfRef` to be possibly undefined.

How is this supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the definite assignment operator `!` which tells the compiler the fields will get initialized in some other way

```
selfRef! :HTMLSpanElement;
```

Comment: Yup, as stated - that's what I'm already doing as a workaround.  But the question is: how this is supposed to work?   Is this the way we're supposed to using React refs with Typescript?  Feels wrong.